# Laravel: ErrorException guraded vs fillable

Tags: laravel-5.1

Laravel:

> ErrorException in Model.php line 2336: in_array() expects parameter 2
>   to be array, string given

```
class Student extends Model
{
protected $guarded = 'student_id'; 

//protected $fillable = ['full_name',  'current_grade','branch']; 
}
```

should I use  `fillable` ? because when I use `guarded` alone its throwing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in an array even when you only have one item in guarded.
protected $guarded = ['student_id'];